# Nuxt.js App is not fetch data with asyncData after reload

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

When I use `asyncData()` function with `setTimeout` and fix data the App is waiting on open or reload the page. When I try now to fetch data from API and only click links over menu to the URL it works fine to, but when I try to load or refresh the page, the App is not waiting for response from API and the fields are blank.

Here are three examples I tried, but none of these are working:

```js
asyncData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get('/api/member/settings').then((response) => {
      resolve({
        Data: {
          User: response.data
        }
      })
    })
  })
}


asyncData() {
  return axios.get('/api/member/settings')
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        Data: res.data
      }
    })
}


async asyncData() {
  let {
    data
  } = await axios.get('/api/member/settings')
  return {
    Data: data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a solution now, instead of the API URI have to be the full URL (http://localhost:3000/api/member/settings) Then its working on reload. :)

Comment: thats not a solution that's a temp fix